# Is there translation of Akhandananda's Tattvadipana in English?

Tags: advaita, translation

Is there translation of Akhandananda's Tattvadipana in English?

I want to understand Advaita better especially the Vivarana School.

Comment: That book is a commentary on the "Pancapadika Vivarana" which is translated in English here: https://archive.org/details/PancapadikaVivarana

Comment: so that book has not been translated, right ?

Comment: Not that I know of.